# How to handle File Download pop up in Firefox using AutoIT in (selenium RC)

Tags: selenium-rc, autoit

I need to download a file from application in my selenium RC test.
When i click on the link/button to save a file, first i get a pop up which asks me to either open or save the file, when i select 'Save' and click 'OK' then i get one more pop up asking me to provide the path where file is to be saved and file name also.
I goggled and found that this could be done via AutoIT but i am facing some problems while doing that.

so could some one please provide me the .exe file for file_download in Firefox and also where i can mention the path to save that file too. 
and also if you could provide me what exactly the code, i need to write in my test case.

Please let me know how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that without using autoit also. follow below steps.

1. Create new firefox profile.
2. Change the preferences in that profile manually before starting the automation with that profile. (Change the settings like below)
   [image]
3. Now start the automation using that profile so that files will be downloaded to default location.

**Starting selenium server using specfic profile**

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -firefoxProfileTemplate "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\234saddsf.customProfile"
```

Comment: You need to specify the profile name while starting the server. I've edited my answer just see.

Answer (score -2):

I found this link: http://qtp-help.blogspot.com/2009/07/selenium-handle-dialogs.html

Unfortunately it is for the old style dialog boxes that do not have the open vs save radio buttons. I'm searching for a solution to this part of the problem.